# MVC – correct pattern – PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Recently I stumbled across different MVC pattern which confuses me. 
I would like to know which does actually fit the most to the MVC architecture.

```
$model = new Model($request); // get data (by routing and url)
$controller = new Controller($model); // pass data for later manipulation
$view = new View($model); // load template (dynamically)
$controller->action(); // update model data (user action)
echo $view->output(); // assign data and output rendered template
```

In the above example, the controller seems to be obsolete and optionally used if there is no user interaction.

```
class Controller{
   $model = new Model($request); // get data
   $view = new View($model); // load template 
}

$controller = new Controller($request);
echo $controller->output();
```

In this example, the controller is rather used to wrap the model and the view. The user action would already be included in the request string and not separated like in the previous example. Furthermore the controller is responsible for the rendered output and not the view.

```
$model = new Model($request); // get data
$view = new View($template); // load template

$controller = new Controller();
echo $controller->output($view, $model);
```

Similar to the previous, the controller is responsible to connect model and view. The template is statically assigned to the view. 
thx!

Comment: The first one. Obsolete != unused. And you use it to perform actions.

Comment: But why shouldn't i already include those actions in the request? I thought the controllers job is to collect information and then to pass it to the Model, as the second one shows.

Comment: The controller has nothing to do with collect information. This is a Layer from the Model. Don't think about a class, if you think about model. Think about repository, value object, busines object.

Comment: Maybe it depends really on the implementation of it. There's actually not much user interaction involved, because this is php, the user cannot really perform actions, only do requests. For a js implementation, this would make indeed more sense, no?

Comment: All three of your "examples" are wrong. Aside from attempting to apply MVC to a tiny codebase (for which it was never intended) you also seem to fail in understanding how information flows from one part of MVC to another.

Comment: Then please help me understand it, instead of just saying i don't ;)